# C# - Connecting to Access2000 DB with Windows-1255 Encoding

Tags: c#, ms-access, database-connection

I'm trying to create a C# program to work with a Ms-Access DB (mdb) which is encoded in Windows-1255 Hebrew.
My Connection string is (Also tried ACE 12.0):

```
"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = mydb.mdb"
```

My queries result turn out to be rubbish, I tried converting the string results after the query with no luck.
I saw that there's a "CharacterSet=1255/windows-1255" but that didn't work (Got Exception saying ISAM not installed"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are 7 different layers to Networking.  You are getting the layers mixed up.  The connection string has nothing to do with the data that is getting stored in the database.  Encoding/Decoding is used to convert a byte[] to a string.  The fields/columns of the data base contains strings  You need to check the format of the columns in Access to see the type.  Then use the same type in c# to read/write the data.

Comment: If your file really *is* an Access_2000 database then it should be storing the Hebrew characters as Unicode (e.g., U+05D7, U+05B2, U+05D1, ..., as illustrated [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCSnH.png)). How was the database created?

Comment: It's a DB of a 3rd party application, I have no control over it.

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked was:

```
private string ConvertStringToHebrewEncoding(sourceStr)
{
    Encoding hebEnc = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255");
    Encoding latinEnc = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");

    byte[] srcBytes = latinEnc.GetBytes(sourceStr);
    return  hebEnc.GetString(srcBytes);
}
```